# How can I record the sound I hear from my soundcard's "Line In"?

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and I have a SoundBlaster Audigy 2 soundcard.

When I plug a 3.5mm into the "Line In" on the soundcard, I can hear the sound coming out of my computer speakers. However, the input level doesn't show any audio activity.

I took the following screen shot while audio was playing (that I can hear just fine) through the Line In:

[image: sound is heard, but no input level with alsa]

And here's a screen shot of my PulseAudio control panel while that same sound is playing. Notice: no input level activity.

[image: sound is heard, but no input level with pavu]

I'm trying to record the sound coming from an external device (that's plugged into the Line In) with Audio-Recorder.

I have tried several "fixes" that involved adding loopback monitoring in PulseAudio, but nothing has worked thus far. Could someone please help me figure out how to record my Line In audio?